# How to get all the transaction logs (insert update delete) for a specific table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, audit-logging

I want to get all the transactions applied on a specific table in SQL Server 2008.

I found the last time a table was updated using this script:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS DatabaseName, last_user_update,*
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'DBName')
AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('tableName')
```

I want to know all the transactions (Inserts, Updates, Deletes) for that table, and their datetime, and the query applied.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Your query doesn't necessarily show the last time the table was updated. You would need a third party log reader tool (and the transaction logs) to determine this for historic data. Is this an ongoing need?

Comment: hey martin I guess we should be able to find such information inside sql withoud using a third party since sql provides log file for each data base

Comment: But it doesn't document the format. You can play around with `sys.fn_dblog` but third party tool vendors have already spent many man hours doing this. You still haven't answered if this is an ongoing need?

Comment: I got a task to know all the dates when a specific table was updated (whether insert or update statement) using sql query only without using a third party

Comment: And you want to do this to investigate something that has already happened or your application needs this functionality on going?

Comment: it will be on going function whenever needed

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this in a reasonable amount of time is to use a third party tool(as Martin said in first comment) such as [ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx) that can read transaction log and get the information you need.

Note that in order for this to work your database has to be in a full recovery mode because that’s when SQL Server logs full transaction details that can be reconstructed later.

Another option is to investigate how to use undocumented fn_dblog function but this will take you a lot more time and you won’t be able to read detached logs or transaction log backups.

Answer (score 2):

creating a trigger which will create a new table Emp_audit and add new tuples to it whenever any change is made to table employee

```
create trigger my_trigger on Employees

AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
DECLARE @What varchar(30);
DECLARE @Who varchar(30);
DECLARE @for int;
DECLARE @At time;
DECLARE @COUNTI int;
DECLARE @COUNTD int;
select @COUNTI = COUNT(*) from inserted;
select @COUNTD = COUNT(*) from deleted;
set @Who = SYSTEM_USER;
set @At = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

if( @COUNTD = 0 and @COUNTI = 1)
    begin
    set @What = 'insert';
    select @for = EmployeeID from inserted i;
    end
else 
    begin
    if( @COUNTD = 1 and @COUNTI = 0)
        begin 
        set @What = 'delete';
        select @for = EmployeeID from deleted i;
        end
    else  
        begin
        set @What = 'update';
        select @for = EmployeeID from inserted i;
        end
    end

     INSERT INTO EMP_Audit Values (@What, @Who, @for, @At);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be much better off setting up auditing for this need rather than trying to extract this information retrospectively from the transaction log.

If you are on Enterprise Edition you could use the built in [SQL Server Audit](http://www.bradmcgehee.com/2010/03/an-introduction-to-sql-server-2008-audit/) functionality, otherwise it should be relative straight forward to log the desired information via triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own transaction logs

Step 1: Create your own table for transaction logs

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TransactionLogs](
 [TransactionLogID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Query] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 [DateCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_TransactionLogs] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [TransactionLogID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Step 2: Create stored procedure that create logs. (Note: Replace YourTablePKColumn with your table primary key column.)

```
create procedure  [dbo].[sp_CreateQueryLogs]
(
    @Query nvarchar(max) = null output,
    @TableName nvarchar(100),
    @YourTablePKColumn nvarchar(30),
    @QueryTypeID tinyint --0 insert, 1 update, 2 delete
) 
as
begin
    declare @object_id bigint, @column_name nvarchar(100), @collation_name nvarchar(50), @column_name_id nvarchar(100) = null, @column_names nvarchar(max) = '', @column_values nvarchar(max) = '', @column_names_create nvarchar(max) = '', @values nvarchar(max) = '', @user_type_id int, @max_length nvarchar(10), @type_name nvarchar(50), @CreateTempTable nvarchar(max) = '', @is_nullable bit, @value nvarchar(max) = ''

    
    create table #tmpValues(ColumnValues nvarchar(max))

    insert into #tmpValues(ColumnValues)
    exec('select CAST ( ( select * from ' + @TableName + ' where YourTablePKColumn = ' + @YourTablePKColumn + '
                    FOR XML PATH(''tr''), TYPE 
        ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) )')

    select @values = ColumnValues from #tmpValues

    if @QueryTypeID = 0 --insert
        set @Query = 'insert into ' + @TableName + '('
    else if @QueryTypeID = 1 --update
        set @Query = 'update ' + @TableName + ' set '
    else if @QueryTypeID = 2 --dalete
        set @Query = 'delete ' + @TableName + ' '

    select @object_id = object_id from sys.tables where name = @TableName

    if not cursor_status('local','columnCursor') <= -1
    begin
        close columnCursor;
        deallocate columnCursor;
    end
    declare columnCursor cursor local for
    select name, user_type_id, convert(nvarchar(10), max_length), is_nullable from sys.columns where object_id = @object_id order by column_id ;
    open columnCursor;
    fetch next from columnCursor 
    into @column_name, @user_type_id, @max_length, @is_nullable;
    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        select @type_name = name, @collation_name = collation_name from sys.types where user_type_id = @user_type_id
        if @column_name_id is null
            set @column_name_id = @column_name
        else
        begin
            set @column_names += @column_name + ', '
            declare @value_keys_start nvarchar(max) = '<' + @column_name + '>', @value_keys_end nvarchar(max) = '</' + @column_name + '>'

            if charindex(@value_keys_start,@values,1) = 0
            begin
                if @QueryTypeID = 0 --insert
                    set @column_values += 'null,'
                else if @QueryTypeID = 1 --update
                    set @column_values += @column_name + ' = null,'
            end
            else
            begin
                if @QueryTypeID = 0 --insert
                    if @collation_name is null and not (@type_name like '%date%' or @type_name like '%time%')
                        set @column_values += substring(@values, charindex(@value_keys_start,@values,1) + len(@value_keys_start), charindex(@value_keys_end,@values,1) - (charindex(@value_keys_start,@values,1) + len(@value_keys_start))) + ','
                    else if @type_name like '%date%' or @type_name like '%time%'
                        set @column_values += '''' + replace(substring(@values, charindex(@value_keys_start,@values,1) + len(@value_keys_start), charindex(@value_keys_end,@values,1) - (charindex(@value_keys_start,@values,1) + len(@value_keys_start))),'T',' ') + ''','
                    else 
                        set @column_values += '''' + replace(substring(@values, charindex(@value_keys_start,@values,1) + len(@value_keys_start), charindex(@value_keys_end,@values,1) - (charindex(@value_keys_start,@values,1) + len(@value_keys_start))),'''','''''') + ''','
                else if @QueryTypeID = 1 --update
                    if @collation_name is null and not (@type_name like '%date%' or @type_name like '%time%')
                        set @column_values += @column_name + '=' + substring(@values, charindex(@value_keys_start,@values,1) + len(@value_keys_start), charindex(@value_keys_end,@values,1) - (charindex(@value_keys_start,@values,1) + len(@value_keys_start))) + ','
                    else if @type_name like '%date%' or @type_name like '%time%'
                        set @column_values += @column_name + '=' + '''' + replace(substring(@values, charindex(@value_keys_start,@values,1) + len(@value_keys_start), charindex(@value_keys_end,@values,1) - (charindex(@value_keys_start,@values,1) + len(@value_keys_start))),'T',' ') + ''','
                    else 
                        set @column_values +=  @column_name + '=' + '''' + replace(substring(@values, charindex(@value_keys_start,@values,1) + len(@value_keys_start), charindex(@value_keys_end,@values,1) - (charindex(@value_keys_start,@values,1) + len(@value_keys_start))),'''','''''') + ''','
            end
        end
        fetch next from columnCursor 
        into @column_name, @user_type_id, @max_length, @is_nullable;
    end
    if not cursor_status('local','columnCursor') <= -1
    begin
        close columnCursor;
        deallocate columnCursor;
    end

    if @QueryTypeID = 0 --insert
        set @Query += substring(@column_names,1,len(@column_names) - 1) + ')
        values (' + substring(@column_values,1,len(@column_values) - 1) + ')'
    else if @QueryTypeID = 1 --update or delete
        set @Query += substring(@column_values,1,len(@column_values) - 1) + ' where YourTablePKColumn = ' + @YourTablePKColumn
    else
        set @Query += ' where YourTablePKColumn = ' + @YourTablePKColumn

end
```

Step 3: Created trigger to table you want to have transaction logs

```
    CREATE TRIGGER trg_MyTrigger ON YouTableName 
AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @TableName nvarchar(100) = 'YouTableName', @Query nvarchar(max), @QueryTypeID tinyint, @YourTablePKColumn nvarchar(30)

    if exists(select * from deleted) and exists(select * from inserted) 
    begin
        set @QueryTypeID = 1
        if not cursor_status('local','updatedCursor') <= -1
        begin
            close updatedCursor;
            deallocate updatedCursor;
        end
        declare updatedCursor cursor local for
        select cast(YourTablePKColumn as nvarchar(30)) from inserted;
        open updatedCursor;
        fetch next from updatedCursor 
        into @YourTablePKColumn;
        while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        begin
            exec dbo.sp_CreateQueryLogs @Query = @Query output, @TableName = @TableName, @YourTablePKColumn = @YourTablePKColumn, @QueryTypeID = @QueryTypeID
            insert into TransactionLogs
                     (Query, DateCreated)
            values (@Query,getdate())
            fetch next from updatedCursor 
            into @YourTablePKColumn;
        end
        if not cursor_status('local','updatedCursor') <= -1
        begin
            close updatedCursor;
            deallocate updatedCursor;
        end
    end
    else if exists(select * from deleted) and not exists(select * from inserted)
    begin
        set @QueryTypeID = 2
        if not cursor_status('local','deletedCursor') <= -1
        begin
            close deletedCursor;
            deallocate deletedCursor;
        end
        declare deletedCursor cursor local for
        select cast(YourTablePKColumn as nvarchar(30)) from deleted;
        open deletedCursor;
        fetch next from deletedCursor 
        into @YourTablePKColumn;
        while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        begin
            exec dbo.sp_CreateQueryLogs @Query = @Query output, @TableName = @TableName, @YourTablePKColumn = @YourTablePKColumn, @QueryTypeID = @QueryTypeID
            insert into TransactionLogs
                     (Query, DateCreated)
            values (@Query,getdate())
            fetch next from deletedCursor 
            into @YourTablePKColumn;
        end
        if not cursor_status('local','deletedCursor') <= -1
        begin
            close deletedCursor;
            deallocate deletedCursor;
        end
    end
    else
    begin
        set @QueryTypeID = 0
        if not cursor_status('local','insertedCursor') <= -1
        begin
            close insertedCursor;
            deallocate insertedCursor;
        end
        declare insertedCursor cursor local for
        select cast(YourTablePKColumn as nvarchar(30)) from inserted;
        open insertedCursor;
        fetch next from insertedCursor 
        into @YourTablePKColumn;
        while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        begin
            exec dbo.sp_CreateQueryLogs @Query = @Query output, @TableName = @TableName, @YourTablePKColumn = @YourTablePKColumn, @QueryTypeID = @QueryTypeID
            insert into TransactionLogs
                     (Query, DateCreated)
            values (@Query,getdate())
            fetch next from insertedCursor 
            into @YourTablePKColumn;
        end
        if not cursor_status('local','insertedCursor') <= -1
        begin
            close insertedCursor;
            deallocate insertedCursor;
        end
    end

END
GO
```